# Equivalent setting in the ServerFlag Section of the option "-keeptty"?

Tags: linux, xorg

Is there a way to include the option "-keeptty" in the ServerFlag section of the Xorg config ? I'm running a Fedora distribution, with systemd, xfce4, lightdm. I cannot find another way to insert this "-keeptty" in the command line used by lightdm. My idea was to try to insert it in the Xorg config. I need this option because I'm trying to debug with gdb. Any other good idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to add it to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` in the line

```
xserver-command=X -background none
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is it possible to insert at this place only the additional options ? The full options passed to Xorg is "-core -noreset :0 -seat seat0 -auth /run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt1 -novtswitch". This is probably generated by lightdm itself. I cannot find it in the config, nor in the systemd service unit.

Comment: There are many other conf files in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` that provide defaults. You should be able to override these if you create a `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/99-my.conf`` with stanza `[Seat:*]` and options. For example, `-nolisten tcp` is presumably controlled by option `xserver-allow-tcp=false`.